# Python List Iteration into One-Liner

Tags: python, list

I'm currently learning Python.

How do I put this:

```
dates = list()  
for entry in some_list:  
    entry_split = entry.split()    
    if len(entry_split) >= 3:  
        date = entry_split[1]
        if date not in dates:  
            dates.append(date)
```

into a one-liner in Python?

Comment: long one-liners are probably not the best thing to dive into for your first day in python.

Comment: Why would you want to?  It *can* be done, but the 1-liner is likely to be less efficient and harder to understand.  1-liners should only be used when they increase the clarity of the code.

Comment: Could be still a lecit question!

Comment: I agree with @SlaterTyranus - what you have looks good!

Comment: @mgilson, list comprehensions will often be faster than building a list one item at a time, but this case doesn't look suitable for one due to the dependence on the partially created list.

Comment: For once, everyone seems to agree to stick with the code I've got. Will do and will keep in mind these suggestions. Thank you all!

Comment: in my opinion, `if date not in dates` means it should not be a one liner.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Right.  In this case, you would need to split the string multiple times though which would negate any speedups you'd gain from the list-comp.  In any case though, the primary reason to use a list-comp is for code clarity, not speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a 1-liner, probably it's easier to understand with a 3-liner.

```
table = (entry.split() for entry in some_list)
raw_dates = (row[1] for row in table if len(row) >= 3)
# Uniquify while keeping order. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257
dates = list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(raw_dates))
```

Comment: I get this error with `import collections`: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'`. Anything missing?

Comment: @dfernandes__: You need to `import collections` first. And you need to use Python 2.7 or 3.x.

Comment: Just updated to version 3.3.2, and your solution works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the order does not matter:

```
dates = set(split[1] for split in (x.split() for x in some_list) if len(split) >= 3)
```

Of course if you want a list instead of a set, just pass the result into `list()`.

Although I would probably stick with what you have, as it is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Really helpful. Will stick with what I've got.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming that set comprehensions are available in your Python version:

```
list({d[1] for d in (e.split() for e in some_list) if len(d) >= 3})
```

If set comprehensions are not available, this will work:

```
list(set(d[1] for d in (e.split() for e in some_list) if len(d) >= 3))
```

But seriously, it's not a good idea to write this as a one-liner, for the reasons mentioned in the comments. Even so, your code can be improved a bit, use a `set` whenever you need to remove duplicates from a collection of elements:

```
dates = set()
for entry in some_list:
    entr_split = entry.split()
    if len(entry_split) >= 3:
        dates.add(entry_split[1])
dates = list(dates)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to split it twice. You can split it in a sublist then check the length outside.

Comment: @2rs2ts ok, I edited my answer. Notice that using a generator expression instead of a list is recommended for the innermost loop

Comment: True enough, I should edit mine to yield too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are splitting every element in `some_list`, checking to see if the split element has 3 or more parts, and taking the second part and appending it to the list if it is not already in the list. You can use a set for this last behavior, since sets only contain unique elements.

```
list(set((entry_split[1] for entry_split in (entry.split() for entry in some_list) if len(entry_split) >= 3]))
```

I re-cast the result to a list because you used a list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
dates = set([entry.split()[1] for entry in some_list if len(entry.split()) >= 3])
```

which gives us what we want:

```
>>> some_list = [
... "a 2011-08-04 b",
... "x y",
... "e 2012-03-04 g"
... ]
>>> dates = set([entry.split()[1] for entry in some_list if len(entry.split()) >= 3])
>>> dates
{'2011-08-24', '2012-03-04'}
```